# how to check weather an element appear only once in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I write a function to compute the numbers that appear only once in a list like `[2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3]`. If more than two numbers are founded, it should return the smallest number and if there is no number with the one-time appearance it should return "Not found".

This is the code that I have written:

```
def one_time(nums, n):
    nums.sort()
    if nums[0] != nums[1]:
        print(nums[0], end = " ")
    for i in range(1, n - 1):
        if (nums[i] != nums[i + 1] and
                nums[i] != nums[i - 1]):
            print( nums[i])
        if nums[n - 2] != nums[n - 1]:
            print(nums[n - 1], end = " ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3]
    n = len(nums)

one_time(nums, n)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd use two sets: one to store the numbers that still might be singles, and one to store the numbers I've found before.  As soon as a number is in the "seen before" list, I can remove it from the singles:

```
def one_time(nums):
    single = set(nums)
    multi = set()
    for n in nums:
        if n in multi and n in single:
            single.remove(n)
        multi.add(n)
    return list(single)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3]
    print(min(one_time(nums)))
```

Comment: This is a nice solution that doesn't require actually counting, but it doesn't handle "multiple candidates" (i.e., where there is more than one number which appears only once, where OP wants the smallest of them). You'd still need to use `min()` on a hopefully smaller input, but worst case `len(single) == len(nums)` and then you're iterating twice essentially. Still a nice solution though.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the `min`.

Answer (score 1):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is the way most people determine how many of each item are in a list. Once you have counts, you can filter by those numbers with only `1` (that the `if v == 1` part), sort and take the `next()` value. `next()` offers the ability to provide a default if nothing is found:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 3]

next((k for k,v in sorted(Counter(l).items()) if v == 1), "Not Found")
# 3

# with no unique elements

l = [2,2,1,1]

next((k for k,v in sorted(Counter(l).items()) if v == 1), "Not Found")
# 'Not Found'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the list elements, and convert into a dictionary with keys = elements of the original list `lst` and values = their number of occurrences in that list.
Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to select only the elements that occurred exactly once.
Select the minimum number from that list.

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3]

cnt = dict(Counter(lst))
print(cnt)
# {2: 3, 1: 3, 5: 1, 3: 1}

try:
  smallest_once = min([x for x, c in cnt.items() if c == 1])
  print(smallest_once)
except ValueError:
  print("Not found")
# 3
```

Comment: You can `try` returning `min(x for x in set(nums) if nums.count(x) == 1)` and catch the `ValueError`, but it still requires iterating through `nums` as many times as there are unique items in `nums`, which turns into a pretty bad solution for large inputs.

Comment: @ddejohn: Thank you for your comment. While my solution is not the most efficient, the code is short and clear.

Comment: Agreed, it was close to what I almost posted. Just giving additional context for future readers.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a set using the list with a different name (e.g. myset = set(mylist))
Then loop through the set and use the built in
.count() function on each element in the set.
Make a variable called counter or something that makes sense and initialize it to zero.
For each iteration, if there is a number that only appears once and counter is equal to zero, save thr number in counter (or a different variable if 0 is a possible number in the list)
If there is another number that appears once, check it's value against the previously saved number.
I hope this helps, and I hope it makes sense, I'm quite tired right now. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally speaking, non-code answers aren't usually received too well. Explaining an algorithm in plain language leads to ambiguity. Try to include code in your answers, or wait until you have enough rep to post this as a comment. And being "tired" isn't really an excuse for not posting code :D